# What tools etc can be used to optimize a PHP web application running on an Windows 2003 IIS 6 server

Tags: php, iis, optimization, monitoring

What would you guys use to monitor an IIS server performance, detect and respond to errors etc, find bottlenecks, visualize CPU utilization under load, monitor PHP MySQL performance etc.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Performance Monitor (perfmon.exe) does a reasonable job.